# Quando editar tags?

Tags: debate, tags, edição

Normalmente vejo muitas questões com uso excessivo de tags, tags sinônimas ou tags dependentes. Sempre busco editar essas questões, para melhorar o filtro do site e ajudar usuários futuros. Criado um banco de informações mais corretas.

#### Exemplo 1

> [image: tags php,mysql,pdo,phpmyadmin,php-7]

No exemplo acima o usuário seleciona muitas tags sobre um mesmo assunto, se ele adiciona a tag [pdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) não precisa informar as tags [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) e [php-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7), já que são informações que se completam.

#### Exemplo 2

> [image: tags php,laravel,hospedagem]

No exemplo acima, temos um erro de informações que são dependentes, se o usuário informa a tag [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel), não precisa informar a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), `laravel` se relaciona diretamente com `php`.

### Problemas

Um dos problemas de múltiplas tags, ou tags dependentes é o uso do filtro de pesquisa por problemas futuramente, onde o usuário com problema com alguma hospedagem do php, não caia em laravel, acidentalmente.

Sempre edito as tags excessivas, mas normalmente não aceitam as edições, mesmo tirando várias tags repetidas, isso já veio a causar bloqueio temporário de edições.

Comment: Não concordo nada com isso, se tem um problema com pdo tem sim de ter a tag php para que os users de php possa ver a pergunta. Um pergunta só com pdo ia-me passar ao lado. A parte de phpmyadmin e php-7 talvez estivesse a mais.

Comment: Então vc concorda com parte disso :^)

Comment: E se a pergunta for sobre JS no Laravel? Apenas com a tag [tag:laravel] não daria para diferenciar. Se a ideia é melhorar a busca, por que uma pergunta sobre JS deveria aparecer para quem está pesquisando sobre o PHP no Laravel?

Comment: Se eu pesquisar pela tag [tag:php] não deveria exibir nos resultado perguntas sobre PDO, sendo que PDO é PHP? Se manter apenas a tag [tag:pdo] isso não acontecerá. Outro fato é que o site utiliza as tags para gerenciar o *syntax higjlight* dos trechos de código, então manter apenas Laravel ou PDO o site não entenderia que deveria aplicar o estilo de PHP.

Comment: Eu já recusei muitas edições sua pelo mesmo problema que o @Woss mencionou. Removia tags super relevantes porque uma já supria a outra, mas no entanto, dificultava (e muito) a busca daquele conteúdo. É importante manter as tags relevantes que descrevem o problema. Se ninguém marcar `laravel` como tag assistida, ninguém vai encontrar aquela questão.

Comment: [Exemplo.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/252563) [Outro exemplo.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/252557) [Aqui tem outro.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/252372) [Mais um.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/252120) Contudo, estes são alguns dos casos que não se aplica a edição de tags.

Comment: @GuilhermeHenriques, eu já rejeitei e modifiquei edições suas por causa desse problema com as tags. Ao invés de você ampliar ou manter o espectro de possíveis pontos de origem para buscas você estava afunilando a quantidade de pontos de origem e assim dificultando a busca pelas questões editadas.

Comment: Só deixando claro para o autor da pergunta que o down-vote aqui no meta significa *não concordo* com o conteúdo da questão levantada e o up-vote significa *concordo* com o conteúdo da questão levantada. Nada relacionado a utilidade, formatação ou qualquer demérito a questão levantada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso quando a pergunta é um debate ou discussão. Quando não é, eu aplico as mesmas regras de voto do SOpt.

Comment: @CypherPotato, entendeu(entendi). :D

Comment: Talvez tenha havido um exagero no exemplo das tags excessivas, mas o foco da pergunta é de quando é excessiva ou não, fico feliz pelo debate que está acontecendo aqui, o exemplo do Laravel em JS foi excelente. A minha questão de ser temporariamente bloqueado das edições foi apenas um detalhe que acrescentei, nada que tenha ficado bravo ou ressentido.

Answer (score 9):

Editar? Quase sempre! Quase todas as perguntas estão com *tags* ruins em algum nível, ou com pouco, ou muita ou errada.

Teve uma época que todos editavam, eu mesmo fazia muito, agora edito só perguntas que eu respondo ou que sejam mais próximas de algo que me interessa porque não dá para fazer tudo sozinho. Editar *tags* é uma das coisas mais importantes.

É claro que tem caso que a edição piora. Um dos problemas é que cada pessoa tem uma visão de como as *tags* devem ser usadas. Elas existam para classificar o conteúdo e facilitar uma busca no futuro. Eu acho que ter mais *tag* é melhor que ter menos *tag* do que deveria.

Sem contexto não dá para afirmar o que está correto ou não.

No primeiro exemplo, o problema é sobre o PDO? Ou ele é está lá circunstancialmente no meio do real problema?

O problema se refere a algo do PHP 7 em específico?

A pessoa está usando o PHPMyAdmin quando deu o problema ou o problema é no PHPMyAdmin? Não é impossível ser diferente, mas pra mim PHP/PDO e PHPMyAdmin são basicamente excludentes, ou você está com problema em um ou está no outro, porque o PHPMyAdmin não roda código escrito em PHP. Já colcoar MySQL e PHPMyAdmin juntas é algo quase obrigatório. Quntas perguntas sobre o PHPMyAdmin não são sobre o MySQL? O oposto não é verdadeiro, até porque muitas vezes quando a pessoa está usando o PHPMyAdmin ele pode estar tendo só problema com o MySQL, e essa ferramenta web nada tem a ver com o problema, é como a confusão que as pessoas fazem com IDE. A pessoa está programando em C# e ela fala que está tendo problema com o Visual Studio sem que este tenha qualquer relação com o problema dela.

A *tag* mais ampla precisa ser sempre usada, não existe isso de redundância. Se a pessoa não colocar PHP como as pessoas respondem sobre isso vão saber que tem uma pergunta sobre o assunto? Ela tem que decorar todas as *tags*, inclusive as novas que vão surgindo que tem vínculo com PHP? E se o assunto tiver vínculo com mais de uma coisa?

No exemplo 2 Hospedagem provavelmente está errado. Quase todas perguntas que estão com esta *tag* não deveriam ter ou deveriam ser perguntas fechadas porque não damos suporte para hospedagem. Sempre tem exceção, mas pra mim essa *tag* é *honey pot*, colocou atrai fechamento.

A questão da PHP é a mesma, precisa. A não ser que o problema seja do Laravel sem envolver PHP. Aí tenho minhas dúvidas se a pergunta é válida no site. Mas aí tem gente que vai dizer que até HTML e CSS não deveria fazer parte do site :D

O problema descrito não costuma acontecer e se acontecer não é um grande problema, tem solução simples: ignora. Já o oposto acontece muito e se acontecer é bem problemático e praticamente não tem o que fazer.

Se eu fosse você eu revisaria todas edições que fez porque provavelmente piorou todas perguntas e criou problemas para a comunidade. Agradecemos a boa vontade, mas algo feito para piorar não tem valor, pelo contrário.

Obrigado por nos informar que estava criando esses problemas, espero que resolve essa questão e outras pessoas reflitam sobre isto.

Se você só fica fazendo edições deste tipo e ainda tem muitas recusas o sistema bloqueará mesmo, pena que não bloqueou antes.

Se a pessoa não entende bem de taxonomia talvez não seja uma boa ideia sair editando as *tags*.